# Cypress not openeing the Test runner on execution of command node_modules/.bin/cypress open

Tags: cypress

On execution of command node_modules/.bin/cypress open  it gives below error-

I have installed cypress using npm package only
npm -i init
npm install cypress --save-dev
When I checked the Cache folder - C:\Users\usename\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.6.0\Cypress
Cypress.exe file is present, but not open when command executed (node_modules/.bin/cypress open)

Cypress version installed is 10.6.0
Error-
It looks like you are running the Cypress binary directly.

This is not the recommended approach, and Cypress may not work correctly.

Please install the cypress NPM package and follow the instructions here:

https://on.cypress.io/installing-cypress

Answer (score 0):

use: "npx cypress open" command

Comment: Would be more useful if you could expand on the answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).